# How to create a table which will be Horizontally and Vertically Scrollable in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've a use-case in which I've to render data in such a way which can be scrollable vertically and horizontally. I'm try a below snippet. Which are getting crash.

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .heightIn(250.dp, max = 350.dp)
            .shadow(5.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
            .background(Color.White)
            .padding(top = 8.dp, bottom = 8.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
   ) {
      // some randow text
      Text("text")
      ProgressBar()

      // drawing table here
      TableView(modifier, viewState)
   }
```

and my `TableView` code is:

```
   @Composable
    private fun TableView(modifier: Modifier, viewState: DashletsViewState) {
        val tableData = viewState.tableData
        val scrollState = rememberScrollState(0)
        val state = rememberLazyListState()
        if (!tableData.isNull()) {
            val rows = tableData.rows.size + 1
            val cols = tableData.columns.flatMap { it.child.orEmpty() }.size + 1
            Box {
                LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize(),
                ) {
                    items(rows) { rowIndex ->
                        Column {
                            LazyRow(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .wrapContentWidth(unbounded = true)
                                    .height(40.dp)
                                    .padding(8.dp)
                                    .background(if (rowIndex == 0) gray14 else Color.White)
                                    .horizontalScroll(scrollState),
                            ) {
                                items(cols) { colIndex ->
                                    Box(
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .size(40.dp)
                                            .padding(4.dp),
                                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                                    ) {
                                        // Content of each grid cell
                                        Text(
                                            text = "($rowIndex, $colIndex)",
                                            color = Color.Black,
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using single `rememberScrollState()` to scroll all `LazyRow`s, it's getting crash at `Modifier.horizontalScroll(scrollState)` and the error message is

```
 Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Horizontally scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum width constraints, which is disallowed. One of the common reasons is nesting layouts like LazyRow and Row(Modifier.horizontalScroll()). If you want to add a header before the list of items please add a header as a separate item() before the main items() inside the LazyRow scope. There are could be other reasons for this to happen: your ComposeView was added into a LinearLayout with some weight, you applied Modifier.wrapContentSize(unbounded = true) or wrote a custom layout. Please try to remove the source of infinite constraints in the hierarchy above the scrolling container.
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this out. I'm stuck. Or can we do it in other ways in Jetpack Compose?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have made 2 fatal wrong code.

1. wrapContentWidth(**unbounded** = true) this code make your component to have more width than maximum capability.
2. In a LazyRow you can't declare **horizontalScroll** property on Modifier. LazyRow handles it automatically.
   Let's try this code :

@Composable

```
private fun TableView(modifier: Modifier, viewState: DashletsViewState) {
    val tableData = viewState.tableData
    if (!tableData.isNull()) {
        val rows = tableData.rows.size + 1
        val cols = tableData.columns.flatMap { it.child.orEmpty() }.size + 1
        Box {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
            ) {
                items(rows) { rowIndex ->
                    Column {
                        LazyRow(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .height(40.dp)
                                .padding(8.dp)
                                .background(if (rowIndex == 0) Color.Gray else Color.White)
                        ) {
                            items(cols) { colIndex ->
                                Box(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .size(30.dp)
                                        .padding(4.dp),
                                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                                ) {
                                    // Content of each grid cell
                                    Text(
                                        text = "($rowIndex, $colIndex)",
                                        color = Color.Black,
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried this but the problem is all ```LazyRows``` scrolling independently. I want to scroll all ```LazyRows``` parallel.